# Java 9 VarHandle Implementation Details

Tags: java, java-9

I have been reading about VarHandle in Java, from the documentation the access modes are grouped into the following categories:

> read access modes, such as reading a variable with volatile memory
>   ordering effects;
>
> write access modes, such as updating a variable with release memory
>   ordering effects;
>
> atomic update access modes, such as a compare-and-set on a variable
>   with volatile memory order effects for both read and writing;
>
> numeric atomic update access modes, such as get-and-add with plain
>   memory order effects for writing and acquire memory order effects for
>   reading.
>
> bitwise atomic update access modes, such as get-and-bitwise-and with
>   release memory order effects for writing and plain memory order
>   effects for reading.

[JEP 193: Variable Handles](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/193)

Found following code sample from [Using JDK 9 Memory Order Modes](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/html/j9mm.html)

```
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.invoke.VarHandle;
class Point {
   volatile int x, y;
   private static final VarHandle X;
   static {
     try {
       X = MethodHandles.lookup().
           findVarHandle(Point.class, "x",
                         int.class);
     } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
       throw new Error(e);
     }
   }
   // ...
}
```

What I am trying to figure out is how does it achieve this, what is the underlying implementation and how to use all these access modes ?

Comment: Two things on this. 1. What precisely as a part of the underlying implementation are you interested in? I hope we are not expecting a complete implementation detailed out here 2. the [documentation if completed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/VarHandle.html) also specifies the methods to use each of those modes. So what actually are you trying to ask here?

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I am trying to understand underlying logic for VarHandle to achieve these access modes and may be some examples. I feel soon it might become a hot interview question, similar to implementation of concurrent packages of Java 5.

Comment: Why would anyone ask how they are *implemented*? Those implementation details are very much subject to change. What matters is the end result, how the java code ultimately maps to machine instructions in JITed code and the memory-ordering behavior and performance characteristics of those instruction sequences. Whether highly disciplined transformations of intermediate representations or rituals involving sacrificial virgins and goat blood get us there doesn't really matter unless you're a JVM engineer.

Comment: @the8472 - Thanks for your response, i liked your last line.. LOL ! Its developer's curiosity :-)